# RAID configuration on new server

Tags: raid5, raid1, server-setup, asus

I need help with the configuration of RAIDs on the ASUS RS720-E10-RS12 server. We have installed 2x 512GB NVME drives in the motherboard slots and 12x SATA SSDs in the Backplane slots. I can only create a RAID from the NVME disks, and the option for RAID for SATAs is then disabled, or I can create a RAID for SATAs, but then the option for NVME RAID is disabled, which is a huge problem.

We need to set up a RAID for the 2 NVME disks (Mirrored) because we want to install VMWare ESXi on them.

Simultaneously, we need to set up RAID 5 or RAID 6 for the 12x SATA SSDs, which will be used for storage.

The problem is, as I mentioned earlier, that if I turn on Intel(R) VROC for NVME, I can create a RAID 1 from these two NVME disks, BUT it automatically switches all my SATAs to AHCI mode, while I need to keep them in RAID mode.

I am trying to configure this through the BIOS - American Megatrends - Aptio Setup - AMI.

So, is there any way to configure one RAID pool from two NVME disks for the system and at the same time another pool from the 12 SATA SSDs for storage?

Comment: Removed unnecessary fluff.

Comment: Can VmWare not do Raid itself? If that is the case, the whole question is irrelevant - RAID the NVME discs for boot, then use VmWare level Raid to raid the storage SSD.

Comment: Hello TomTom, as far as i know, there is no way I can configure RAID in VMWare ESXi. Maybe I am missing some knowledge but everybody is saying that can´t be done.

Comment: Well, not a VmWare user here - I use Hyper-V, but I would find thae lack of any sofware level raid astonishing. Hyper-V on Windows does that - with Raid across multiple servers - out of the box, and I am always told VmWare is better...

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was told too – that VMware is better.

Comment: And as per answer from NISMO1968 there IS a raid possibility.

Comment: We switched from VMware to Proxmox VE entirely a few years back. Our Linux expertise really paid off: We found it amazingly more comfortable to work with PVE than VMware. MD-RAID, LVM and even ZFS are easily manageable as PVE is just Debian under the hood.

Comment: Maybe you just need a real RAID controller.

Comment: I have installed two PIKE II 3108-8i controllers. Now, I am able to create RAID through Intel VROC for NVME drives on the motherboard. Additionally, I can create hardware RAID arrays through the Avago MegaRaid in the BIOS for SATA disks, which is fantastic.

However, I have encountered an issue. I noticed that there are TWO Avago MegaRaid entries in the BIOS. In one of them, I can see 8 SATA disks, and in the second one, I see the remaining 4 SATA disks. My question is: Can I create a RAID configuration using both controllers, so that all 12 SATA disks will be included in the RAID setup?

Comment: @demon420 no you can't make RAID across 2 RAID controllers. You need one controller with more ports such as 3108-16i.

Comment: You can't manage RAID with vmware vsphere but vmware vsan do this.  But vsan is another thing,  is an HCI that demands another licence.

Answer (score 8):

VMware doesn't support any sort of a software RAID concept, so you're out of luck here. What you can do however:

I. Software RAID

(1) Keep your UEFI-controlled & mirrored NVMe drives as a boot option. As long as VMware is OK with your pseudo-hardware RAID, of course! You should be fine with vROC & ESXi so far.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/85889

(2) Chop some part of the mirrored NVMe space as a local VM datastore.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc/GUID-5F08F7A7-6D8E-45A6-B408-278B3A4C7D4C.html

(3) Configure a VM with powerful software RAID, doing either whole controller PCI pass-thru or just individual SATA SSDs pass-thru. There are two options basically: FreeBSD-based TrueNAS "Core" (Debian Linux-based "Scale" shouldn't be used due to the overall immaturity) and Linux-based StarWind SAN & NAS. Later is preferred actually as unlike TrueNAS it supports both ZFS and MDRAID+XFS combo which is faster for SSDs, and has pre-built VMware virtual machine deployment out-of-box.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/san-and-nas

(4) After you have it done you add iSCSI or NVMe-oF connection in a loopback and configure a new VM datastore, this one is software RAID protected.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/8.0/vsphere-storage/GUID-9C92500A-A408-4E91-BBA6-D90B5995D891.html

II. Hardware RAID

You can keep booting your system from the software-mirrored NVMe drives and just drop in an extra LSI RAID controller just for SATA SSDs. You won't get any better performance or data integrity as both ZFS and MDRAID+XFS rock, but at least it might be less complicated to manage. Just make sure your new shiny RAID is on VMware HCL.

https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=44985

Comment: While that is a creative solution for (possibly) no extra cost, I'd *seriously* recommend adding a ESXi-certified RAID controller.

Comment: Watch out for option "II. Hardware RAID" in my original post.

Comment: It was there from the very beginning. I just changed formatting. View history. If you can...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/posts/1142543/revisions

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/o4eMymF

Answer (score 3):

The ASUS RS720-E10-RS12 uses an Intel PCH C621A, which supports VROC (for the NVME drives) **or** RSTe (for the SATA drives), depending on BIOS configuration.

Anyway, [VMWare does not support RAID arrays based on RSTe](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/ESXi-Hardware-RAID-ISSUE/td-p/2312268), so you are not going to see your SATA array inside VMWare.

As a side note, "VMWare is better" generally refer to its leading position as virtualization platform. But the hardware support provided by QEMU/KVM (Linux) or HyperV (Windows) is much larger. For VMWare you should [search the HCL](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) (hardware compatibility list) *before* buying anything.